# Touchpad relative position

Tags: arch-linux, touchpad

I've just installed ArchLinux on my new Xiaomi Air 13.3 and the touchpad seems to be working on absolute coords instead of relative.
How change it to a normal behaviour?

Comment: Interesting behavior. How does it feel when touchpad works in relative coords? How did you realize that you touchpad doesn't talk with rel but with abs cords?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

I found the answer here: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=215640

Solution is this:

```
sudo pacman -S xf86-input-libinput && sudo pacman -R xf86-input-evdev
```

Then restart your X server (a reboot would also work).

The issue arises during the installation of the `xorg-server` package, when it gives you two options to choose from: xf86-input-evdev and xf86-input-libinput, but the evdev version is the default.

Comment: fwiw, you don't actually need to remove evdev, xf86-input-libinput has a higher sorting order so it'll take over automatically.